# I'm trying to control a servo with a push of a button but its not working HELP

Tags: servo, button

I'm new to Arduino and I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2HMJiy9b_I   but the problem is the servo just keeps moving back and forwards on it own and the button is doing nothing when pressed please help.

Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
#define servoPin 3 //~
#define pushButtonPin 2 

int angle =90;    // initial angle  for servo
int angleStep =5;
const int minAngle = 50;
const int maxAngle = 110;

int buttonPushed =0;

void setup() {
  // Servo button demo by Robojax.com
  Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial
  myservo.attach(servoPin);  // attaches the servo on pin 3 to the servo object
  pinMode(pushButtonPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
   Serial.println("Robojax Servo Button ");
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(pushButtonPin) == LOW){
    buttonPushed = 1;
  }
   if( buttonPushed ){
  // change the angle for next time through the loop:
  angle = angle + angleStep;

    // reverse the direction of the moving at the ends of the angle:
    if (angle <= minAngle || angle >= maxAngle) {
      angleStep = -angleStep;
       buttonPushed = 0;
    }
    myservo.write(angle); // move the servo to desired angle
      Serial.print("Moved to: ");
      Serial.print(angle);   // print the angle
      Serial.println(" degree");    
  delay(100); // waits for the servo to get there
   }


}
```

Comment: I posted the code:https://robojax.com/learn/arduino/?vid=robojax_Servo_PB2_move_one_direction. I need help with the code so when the button is pressed the servo will rotate 0 to 180 degrees and stop but the button is unresponsive and the servo just keeps moving back and forth

Comment: Edit your question. Select all of the code, and tap the `{}` code formatting button. Your code is unreadable as posted.

Comment: ok how about now

Comment: Once you push the button once and buttonPushed becomes 1 the servo will move forever because nothing ever sets buttonPushed back to 0.  You need an else there to set it back to 0.

Comment: sorry, but I don't really know how to do that. :(

Comment: Also you should use a pull down resistor if not already doing so.

Comment: Actually that code sets buttonPushed to 0 when the angle reaches one of the limits. From that code I would expect the servo to move to one of it's limits and stop if you pressed the button for a very short time. As long as you hold the button down I would expect the servo to keep moving back and forth.

Comment: The button appears to be wired through the pin to ground, and using INPUT_PULLUP mode on the pin. That should work. As long as you hold down the button, the servo should move back and forth. When you let go of the button it should stop almost immediately (within 1/10th of a second.)

Comment: i posted some code that shows how to detect the button being pressed at the moment that you press it, but it does not keep detecting a button press if you hold the button .... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/74876/restart-sequence-of-neopixel-stick-with-a-push-button-at-any-time/74949#74949

Comment: if it start shaking on it own. it might be electrical problem.
How you power the system?

Answer (score -1):

This condition below is never met because a boolean comparison is implied :

```
if( buttonPushed ){
```

and buttonPushed is declared as :

```
int buttonPushed =0;
```

A proper comparison should be OK :

```
if( buttonPushed == 1) 
{ 
   // Do something
}
```

Also the buttons need proper debouncing or the push event will have undetectable results :

https://dduino.blogspot.com/2012/03/arduino-button-debouncing.html

[image]

Comment: C++ will treat any non-zero value as true and 0 as false.  It is perfectly legal to use an int inside an if statement in this way.   If you would like I can post demonstration code to prove it.  It not great coding style, but it won't cause any failure.

Comment: An if statement works with integers!

Comment: Mea culpa you are right :
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/constants/constants/